# How to convert a m3u8 playlist file into a video segment

Tags: ffmpeg

I've been trying to find out solutions but could not, on how to extract a video segment (say an mp4) from a given m3u8 file, where the video starts from some offset and has a particular duration. Wish someone could help.

I tried this:

```
ffmpeg -i http://foo.herokuapp.com/input_test.m3u8 -acodec copy -vcodec copy  -y -loglevel info -f mp4 myNewVideo.mp4
```

It generates the video, but now I need it to start from a particular offset and it needs to last a particular duration. I know that the offset might need the -ss flag, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Share some code to understand better your issue please

Comment: I am using this: ffmpeg -i http://foo.herokuapp.com/input_test.m3u8 -acodec copy -vcodec copy  -y -loglevel info -f mp4 myNewMp3.mp4

It works. But I need the output to start from a particular offset from the beginning and the video needs to a particular duration long.

Comment: Post it on the question so then people could see it better

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Examples for a capture starting at 30s (`-ss`)  with a duration of 10s (`-t`).

If the input HLS playlist is of type **VOD** you can do:

`ffmpeg -ss 00:00:30 -i http://foo.herokuapp.com/input_test.m3u8 -t 10 -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -flags +global_header -y output.mp4`

If the input is a **Live** stream then:

`ffmpeg -i http://foo.herokuapp.com/input_test.m3u8 -ss 00:00:30 -t 10 -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -flags +global_header -y output.mp4`

The seek is done on the output in the second case (`-ss` after `-i`).

You can also add a `-re` before `-i` for the live stream if you want to avoid fetching the latest 3 segments at once when you execute the command.